# Populate dropdown based on selection of parent category

Tags: categories, ajax

I have a category structure of Places within Regions. I want to show a list of Region categories in a dropdown list then populate a second dropdown of the Places in the first selection in an input form.

Secondly, I want to be able to make multiple selections so I end up with Place, Place etc.

I can generate the first dropdown, but cannot see how I use that selection to populate the second.